# Does anyone know how to make python go to the system default tk installation (on Linux) for the tkinter install in the make/configure process

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tkinter, debian

So I have been trying to install Python3.9 with tkinter for a bit now and I have finally come up with a mediocre solution with one problem which is I can't figure out how to make python use the tk8.6-dev package on Debian to install the _tkinter module.

Edit 2 hours later: Figured out answer to first problem. Now need help finding out how to make python successfully find the tcl.h file in `/usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl-private/generic/`
and the tk.h file in
`/usr/include/tcl8.6/tk-private/generic/`.

Comment: You can specify tcl/tk include directories with the option `--with-tcltk-includes` when running `configure`.  Also you need to specify the tcl/tk lib directories with the option `--with-tcltk-libs` as well.  Refer the description by running `./configure --help`.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried building with the proper paths to the libraries and the include files but in the make command it returns Fatal error /usr/bin/linux_Arch/tcl8.6/tcl-private/tcl.h No file named 'tcl.h' even though when I cd over  there it shows the file

Comment: Should it be `/usr/lib/...` instead of `/usr/bin/...`? Normally include files will not put in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I tried again with minor changes and now make is returning ```Following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
_tkinter                ``` da heck does this mean

Comment: Most probably the tcl/tk libraries cannot be found.

Comment: I shall play around with what i put in the --with-tcltk-libs option and see what happens

Comment: Ahh yes now i think that my python is just being straight up idiotic or my tcl.h file is broken.

Comment: If tcl/tk header files are in `/usr/local/include` and libs are in `/usr/local/lib`, use `--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'`.